# Ignite Distributed Closures vs Akka (Remote) Actors

Tags: akka, ignite

It seems that the [distributed closures in Ignite](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-closures) grow more towards the functionality (remote) actors in Akka provide.

To what extend are they overlapping or complementary (state, behaviour, supervision, children,...)? the documentation for Ignite is a little concise on this topic and it could be that I am comparing apples and pears, but then I want to know also...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distributed closures in Ignite are just that: closures that can be executed on remote Ignite nodes without any explicit deployment (unicast, broadcast, etc.). They don't impose traditional Actor (a-la Akka) semantics. In Ignite it's done on purpose.

This is a pretty good example of what's possible with Ignite closures in Scala: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/ignite/scalar/examples/ScalarPingPongExample.scala

Comment: Two more questions: 1) Can you elaborate more in your answer on how that is done without expliciet deployment? In other words, how is the code being 'moved' towards remote nodes? 2) If I want to have a fault tolerance solution like in Akka (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/java/fault-tolerance.html), for example where a child not would be a cluster singleton that must execute an ftp call, how would I do that? Do I have to implement the whole error handling explicitly?